# Configuring Postgresql 9.1 and PostGIS 2 on Ubuntu 13

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, postgis

I'm following [this manual](http://hackgeo.com/cloud-computing/amazon-web-services/configuring-postgresql-9-1-and-postgis-2-on-ubuntu-12-04-in-amazon-aws) to Configuring Postgresql 9.1 and PostGIS 2 on Ubuntu 13 in Amazon AWS, when trying to execute the command:

```
/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf
```

I get the following error

```
/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf: Permission denied
```

i tried

```
sudo /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf
```

and got:

```
postgres is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

so i created a user and added it to the sudo group and tried again, without `sudo` i got permission denied with it i got:

```
sudo: /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf: command not found
```

but when trying `ls -a /etc/postgresql/9.1/main` pg_hba.conf appears.

any suggestions?

Comment: `pg_hba.conf` is a text file, it has to be edited (as opposed to launched which is what the above commands are unsuccessfully trying). The tutorial should read `vi /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf`

Comment: @DanielVérité thanks for the help! continuing with the tutorial i'm running the command `sudo apt-get update` and get lots of warnings and errors for example: `Err http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main amd64 Packages` or: `W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sharpie/for-science/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found`, any ideas?

Comment: I'd suggest to make it a new question on [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com), since installation troubleshooting is off-topic here.